# Using Ubuntu of a USB device

Tags: boot, usb, games

How can I get to the following scenario:

1. At my house I install Ubuntu on a USB flash drive and install Steam and some games on it
2. At school I can boot of it and play the installed games and use the installed software

I tried to make a bootable USB device and got to the point where I had working Ubuntu in front of me (I chose "Try Ubuntu" when booting in). It was booted of the USB and nothing was installed on the computer as expected. I installed Steam and couple of games. After rebooting Steam and the games were gone. What went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

To do what you're asking you'll need to create a persistent USB drive. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LiveUsbPendrivePersistent

Just keep in mind that if you were wanting to install Steam on it as well you'll probably want to have a 64GB or larger flash-drive, and you will also need to have it initially formatted in FAT32 format.

Comment: I see the page you linked me is pretty old and find it a little hard to follow. Do you have anything newer?